# svn: error occurred while committing the transaction

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, svn

Can someone help me debug this issue? Everything works (i.e. I can commit, checkout, etc.) but this one commit always fails as described below. I tried checking out in a new repository, and committing, but same issue. Note also that this is a very large repository (500GB), and a very large commit (36k files totaling 10GB).

This is the `apache2` error log:

```
[Sat Feb 10 03:25:16.262765 2018] [dav:error] [pid 3339] [client X.X.X.X:61908] Could not DELETE /svn/repo/!svn/txn/463-e8.  [500, #0]
[Sat Feb 10 03:25:16.265881 2018] [dav:error] [pid 3339] [client X.X.X.X:61908] could not abort transaction.  [500, #2]
[Sat Feb 10 03:25:16.265905 2018] [dav:error] [pid 3339] [client X.X.X.X:61908] Transaction '463-e8' cleanup failed  [500, #2]
[Sat Feb 10 03:25:16.265923 2018] [dav:error] [pid 3339] [client X.X.X.X:61908] Can't remove '/mnt/vc/svn/repo/db/transactions/463-e8.txn/node._ji.0'  [500, #2]
[Sat Feb 10 03:25:16.265940 2018] [dav:error] [pid 3339] [client X.X.X.X:61908] Can't remove file '/mnt/vc/svn/repo/db/transactions/463-e8.txn/node._ji.0': No such file or directory  [500, #2]
[Sat Feb 10 03:25:30.640591 2018] [dav:error] [pid 2966] [client X.X.X.X:61712] Could not MERGE resource "/svn/repo/!svn/txn/463-e8" into "/svn/repo/repofolder".  [500, #0]
[Sat Feb 10 03:25:30.642889 2018] [dav:error] [pid 2966] [client X.X.X.X:61712] An error occurred while committing the transaction.  [500, #160014]
[Sat Feb 10 03:25:30.643003 2018] [dav:error] [pid 2966] [client X.X.X.X:61712] Reference to non-existent node '_1bqk.0.t463-e8' in filesystem '/mnt/vc/svn/repo/db'  [500, #160014]
```

The client side gives:

```
done
Committing transaction...
svn: E175012: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175012: Connection timed out
svn: E200042: Additional errors:
svn: E175002: Unexpected server error 500 'Internal Server Error' on '/svn/repo/!svn/txn/463-e8'
```

First I thought this was a permission issue. So I did this on the server:

```
su - www-data -s /bin/bash -c "svnadmin rmtxns /mnt/vc/svn/repo/ 463-e8"
Transaction '463-e8' removed.
```

No error whatsoever. Apache runs as `www-data`. Following permissions are set:

```
chown www-data:www-data /mnt/vc -R
chmod 0774 /mnt/vc -R
```

I have run `svnadmin verify` and found no problems. `dmesg` doesn't show anything new.

The apache svn config is pretty much default.

```
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
# Set to 10h.
Timeout 36000

SVNCompressionLevel 5
SVNInMemoryCacheSize 16384
SVNCacheTextDeltas On
SVNCacheFullTexts On
SVNAllowBulkUpdates Prefer

<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /mnt/vc/svn
    SVNListParentPath On

    # Allow large request
    LimitXMLRequestBody 0
</Location>
```

Extra info:

```
Server: Debian 9.3
apache2/stable,stable,now 2.4.25-3+deb9u3 amd64 [installed]
libapache2-mod-svn/stable,stable,now 1.9.5-1+deb9u1 amd64 [installed]
Server svn client: 1.9.5-1+deb9u1 
Client: svn 1.9.7
```

**EDIT:** I copied the working copy to the repository server. Then I tried to commit, but had the same error. I then relocated the working copy to direct repository location: `svn relocate file:///mnt/vc/svn/repo`. Commit worked this time. So it has to do something with `dav_svn`?

Same question was asked in [subversion-users mailing list](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-users/201802.mbox/%3CMWHPR03MB32796BC84808A38387A077A2A7F70%40MWHPR03MB3279.namprd03.prod.outlook.com%3E).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a client-side problem that results in weird server side errors.

After the client transfers all the files to the server, the server starts commiting them into the repository. During this time, the client gets no response, and if it takes longer than the default timeout, then the client closes the connection, resulting in the above error on the server side.

> One change in 1.8 is that serf is used to handle HTTP on the
>   client-side rather than neon. The default client-side HTTP timeout
>   when using neon is 60 minutes but when using serf it is 10 minutes. A
>   client can change its default timeout by setting
>   servers:global:http-timeout.[<sup>1</sup>](https://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2014-10/0075.shtml)

And [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html) is the documentation for the `servers` file.

Setting `http-timeout = 3600` under the `[global]` tag effectively fixes the problem.